# IllegalStateException while acessing FragmentManager inside RecyclerAdapter class with the help of activity's object

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

I am trying to open a dialog box from my Recycler adapter onClick of a button.
For that i need to get the FragmentManager using the getFragmentManager method ,which can only be called with the help of the activity object .

Here is my code :

RecyclerAdapter2 :

```
   package com.example.batrad.expenseassist;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.Image;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by batrad on 11/18/2016.
     */

public class RecyclerAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter2.MyViewHolder> {
    List<Information2> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    Activity activity;
    FragmentManager fm;

    public RecyclerAdapter2(Context context, List<Information2> data) {
        activity=(Activity)context;
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
         fm=activity.getFragmentManager();


    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter2.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =inflator.inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_category,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter2.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("tag",data.get(0)+"");
        Information2 info=data.get(position);
        Log.d("testre",info.categoryName+info.amount);
        holder.categoryName.setText(info.categoryName);
        holder.amount.setText(info.amount+"");
        holder.categoryImage.setImageResource(info.categoryImage);

    }

    public void onInsert(int size){
        notifyItemInserted(size);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView categoryName;
        TextView amount;
        ImageView categoryImage;
        ImageView deleteIcon;
        ImageView addIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categoryName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            amount=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            categoryImage=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryImage);
            deleteIcon=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);
            addIcon=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addIcon);
            addIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SubCategoryDialog subCategoryDialog=new SubCategoryDialog();
            SubCategoryDialog.setValues(data.get(getAdapterPosition()).categoryName);
            subCategoryDialog.show(fm, "Create Category");


        }
    }
}
```

Inside the constructor of RecyclerAdapter2 I am passing the context of the activity from my MainActivity Java file:

MainActivity.java :

```
 categoryrecycleAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter2(this, getdata());
```

Inside RecyclerAdapter2 constructor i assign the context to Activity class's object .

And than i use the object to get the fragmentManager.
 But i am getting IllegalStateException here :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1433)
                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
                                                                                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
                                                                                      at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
                                                                                      at com.example.batrad.expenseassist.RecyclerAdapter2$MyViewHolder.onClick(RecyclerAdapter2.java:85)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
```

Please help .

Comment: Not the right way to do this.Use an interface for listening to the clicks and implement it in your activity.Ask if you need eg..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to attach listeners. You should set the onClickListener in the constructor of your viewholder and should send a callback to your fragment using an interface as shown below or you can also use BaseAdapter from [this](https://gist.github.com/aurae/ebf8ec212e4296aebb24) or [this](https://gist.github.com/IshankGulati/1e1390ad8a1bace27ea6900dbd35467c).

```
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View v);
    }

    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public RecAdapter(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemCLick(v);
            }
        });
    }
```